# Transform Blob from XmlHttpRequest without loading it completely into memory

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, fileapi

I want to implement a client-side file decryption in the browser. It takes decrypted files from a server and should decrypt it in the browser, presenting a *Save As* dialog to save the decrypted file. It should also work for large files (1 GB or more).

I have the following strategy in mind:

- Download the file using `XMLHttpRequest` with `responseType = 'blob'`.
- Decrypt by transforming the Blob given by `XMLHttpRequest`.
- Provide the decrypted Blob as a `objectURL` to the user.

The decryption could work like a stream transformation, it reads chunks from the downloaded Blob, decrypts the data and writes into the output Blob.

However as far as I can tell this will only work with current browsers if you can load the whole file into memory (you need to store the complete decrypted blob in memory before you can create an `objectURL`). It seems that no kind of chunked reading/writing is supported by the current `Blob`, `XMLHttpRequest` and `createObjectURL` interface as described on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).
A Blob is immutable and there doesn't seem to be an streaming support for binary data in browsers.

Is there any way to implement this with current browsers?

Answer (score 0):

After getting a `Blob` with `responseType = 'blob';`, you can use [`blob.slice(start, end)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.slice) to get a subview and use the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API to grab the data associated with this subview.

Comment: Sure. But can I read a chunk of the response, write it to a new blob  and start saving the file without finishing the response first. I don't want to keep the whole file in memory before saving it to the users disk.

Comment: @GregorMüllegger That's a different question. In Firefox, you can use `responseType = 'moz-blob'` (e.g. in progress events). Other browsers do not yet support streaming XHR response bodies. You can use HTTP Range requests if you want to effectively stream in all browsers (today). The server must support this standard feature though, in order to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks. The gist of my question is that I want to let a user save a file from the server. But in-between I want to modify (decrypt) the file in the browser without needing to have the whole file in memory before saving it to disk all at once. Range requests are a good idea! But they only solve part of the problem, leaving the chunked writing of the file to the users disk.

Comment: @GregorMüllegger In Chrome, you could use `requestFileSystem` to get a sandboxed filesystem to write the intermediate chunks in order to get the complete file without having to store it in-memory. In Firefox, you could use `IndexedDB` for that purpose (and use the `Blob` constructor to re-assemble the file).